# Spring app produces 2 jars - executable and as a dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have a Spring project with a pom file. After building it I want to produce 2 jars, one executable and one as a dependency. Using this article: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-build.html  I added the following plugin at my pom file:

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <classifier>exec</classifier>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
</plugin>
```

When building the project I received the following error no main manifest attribute in jar.
Could you please advice me how to resolve the error?

Comment: Hi @Sardothien. Can you share what error did you receive ? If your build is successful, the two jars would be generated.

Comment: I have a little progress: Yes, 2 jars are generated xyz.jar and xyz-exec.jar. So at my other project pom I have to add one of this local jars as a dependency. Please, advice me how to do that?

Comment: Okay. I think 3 things need to be done now:
1. Look into Multi Module Maven project structure.
2. Update this project's pom to not to product "fat" jar.
3. Configure other project's pom to use this one as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paras! This works for me! :))